# Linux max server processes

Tags: linux, load, average

I have a GNU/Linux Debian server running: apache, jboss, proftpd and postgresql (RAM: 16GB, 4 core Xeon). Max Apache process is 1200, same thing for the Jboss DB Pool. And I can have up to 400  simultaneous FTP download. Load average can raise 5 (1 most of time).  What do you think about that? Is this server considered as "too loaded"?

Regards,

Comment: This question is a better fit for serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off with less threads for some of your components. Having too many is actually less efficient. You are better off with a queue and being able to process your work more efficiently, allowing the threads to spend more time working and less time context switching.

That being said, I would not say that a server with a load average of 1 is too loaded. It might be working hard, but if there is only one process that is ready for a CPU at a time, on average, that is not bad at all.

Is it "too slow"?

Jacob